# Как зайти на локалку с другого компьютера?

Tags: denwer, сеть, php

У меня есть 2 компьютера, связанные через Wi-Fi. На них поставлен Denwer. Я работаю с братом, он помогает с вёрсткой. И вот хотелось бы чтобы он мог править со своего компа на моей локалке, а точнее не править, а видеть результат, т.е. открывать мою локалку в браузере у себя. А то не удобно: заливать с его локалки его работу, мою работу на его локалку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [официальном FAQ](http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html) Денвера описано, как расшарить сайт на другие машины в сети. Чтобы не перекидывать ваши работы между компьютерами, можно расшарить папку с сайтом по FTP. Правда, могут возникнуть проблемы, если вы вдвоём начнёте одновременно работать над одним файлом. Для предотвращения таких конфликтов, рекомендую пользоваться системой контроля версий.

Comment: Спасибо, думал всё просто, у меня динамический ИП, каждый день менять ип адресс и наименование папки - не вариант, проще делать как делал(

Comment: @mctrane если у вас wi-fi через роутер - можно намертво привязать определенные ip к определенным mac-адресам (читай: к определенным сетевым картам определеннных компьютеров). То есть зарезервировать за вашим компьютером, например, ip-шник 192.168.0.100 чтобы DHCP роутера не выдавал его никому кроме вашего компьютера.